# ListView doesn't appear in xamarin

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, xamarin

Greetings i'm trying to develop android app using xamarin where the layout has view pager with 8 elements each with list view in it ... every thing works fine i'm following the tutorial [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview's_appearance/)
but the listview doesnot appear 
here is my axml for the list view

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
        <CheckBox
            android:text="@string/Date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
        <CheckBox
            android:text="alert"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/newsFeedList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my axml code for the listview cell

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contentImageView1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contentTextView1"
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the following is my code for the viewpager fragment

```
using System;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Android.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Content;
namespace test
{
    public class ContentFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        private ViewPager homeViewPager;
        public ContentFragment ()
        {
        }
        override public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState){
            var rootView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.HomeContent, container,false);
            homeViewPager = rootView.FindViewById<ViewPager>  (Resource.Id.homeViewPager);
            homeViewPager.Adapter = new HomePagerAdapter (MainActivity.fragmentManager);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

and following is my adapter for the view pager

```
using System;
using Android.Support.V4.App;

namespace test
{
    public class HomePagerAdapter:FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        public HomePagerAdapter (FragmentManager fm):base(fm)
        {
        }
        public override int Count {
            get {
                return 8;           
            }

        }
        public override Fragment GetItem (int position)
        {
            //return ListFragment;
            return new FeedsFragment ();
            //return f;
        }
    }
}
```

following is my code for the listview fragment

```
namespace test
{
    public class FeedsFragment:Fragment
    {
        ListView feedsList;
        List<FeedsModel>modelList;
        FeedsModel model;
        public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            try{
                View rootView = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.NewsFeedList, container, false);
            model = new FeedsModel ();
            modelList=new List<FeedsModel>();
             feedsList = rootView.FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.newsFeedList);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                model.feedContent="once upon the time tow boys and a girl saied bla bla bla and did blablablab and tha't some text yup uakfjjkd;f";
                model.imageURI = "g";
                modelList.Add(model);
            }

            feedsList.Adapter = new FeedsAdapter (MainActivity.context, modelList);
                return rootView;}
                catch(Exception e){{
                    Toast.MakeText (MainActivity.context, e.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    return base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

following is the adapter for the listview

```
amespace test
{
    public class FeedsAdapter:BaseAdapter<FeedsModel>
    {   private Activity activity;
        private List<FeedsModel> data;
        public FeedsAdapter (Activity activity, List<FeedsModel> data):base()
        {


                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                this.activity = activity;
                this.data = data;

        }
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override FeedsModel this[int position] {  
            get { return data[position]; }
        }
        public override int Count {
            get { return data.Count; }
        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is available
            if (view == null) // otherwise create a new one
                view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.NewsFeedListItem, null);
            Toast.MakeText (activity, "tetet", ToastLength.Long).Show ();
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.contentTextView1).Text = data[position].feedContent;
            view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.contentImageView1).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

finally is my data model

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    public class FeedsModel
    {
        private String _imageURI;
        public String imageURI{
            set{this._imageURI=value;}
            get{return this._imageURI;}
        }
        private String _feedContent;
        public String feedContent{
            set{this._feedContent=value;}
            get{return this._feedContent;}
        }
        public FeedsModel ()
        {


        }
    }
}
```

thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you've accidentally set `android:orientation` to `horizontal` instead of `vertical` in your root layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" <-- Set this to vertical
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
        <CheckBox
            android:text="@string/Date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
        <CheckBox
            android:text="alert"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/newsFeedList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```